# How call in -(IBAction)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ibaction

I'm new in objective-c.
Need to make a button link, which will open in a new window. To do this I need to do IBAction to create a new window.
This add WebView :

```
- (ERBrowser *)addWebView:(NSURL *)url{
    for (NSView *view in browserViews)
        [view setHidden:true];
    ERTabModel *newModel = [[ERTabModel alloc] init];
    NSTabViewItem *newItem = [[NSTabViewItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:newModel];
    [tabView addTabViewItem:newItem];
    [tabView selectTabViewItem:newItem];
    ERBrowser *browserView = [[ERBrowser alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.frame];
    [browserView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
    [mainView addSubview:browserView];
    [browserViews addObject:browserView];
    [browserView setUIDelegate:self];
    [browserView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
    if (url)
        [[browserView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    return browserView;
}
```

This link for button :

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkButton:(NSButton*)sender
{
    ERBrowser *browserView = [browserViews objectAtIndex:[tabView indexOfTabViewItem:[tabView selectedTabViewItem]]];
    [[browserView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sender alternateTitle]]]];
    [self addNewTab:(id)];
```

And this IBAction add new tab :

```
- (IBAction)addNewTab:(id)sender {

    [self addWebView:(NSURL *)];
}
```

I can not understand that as a cause addWebView `[self addWebView:(NSURL *)];`
And how to add addNewTab `[self addNewTab:(id)];`

Please explain how to do it?

Comment: `IBAction` is a special keyword that the compiler recognizes.  It is used to identify methods which can be selected to be "actions" when editing a NIB.  It has no other function/meaning, and, if not "linked" in the NIB editor, it has no effect at all.

Comment: Thank you that I can understand. Here the question is quite different. I need this IBAction transfer function, but I do not understand how can I transfer it to the present case.
When do you get a static URL like this  `[self addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];` i not understand how call not static url for another function `[self addWebView:[NSURL URLWithString:HERE WOT WHRITE]];`

Comment: What do you mean by "IBAction transfer function"??  What does IBAction have to do with accessing a URL?

Comment: I need to have opened a new tab addNewTab panel, add to it and opened the WebView url from which it was caused.
Like if I enter the URL in NSTextField, that would open in a new window and load url wot i whrite

Comment: Sorry this question is canceled. I did everything wrong, already understand how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `(type)`, e.g. `(NSURL *)`, in a *method declaration* defines the type of a parameter, e.g.:

```
- (ERBrowser *)addWebView:(NSURL *)url
```

declares a method `addWebView:`, which takes a single parameter of type `NSURL *`, and within that method the parameter is referred to using the name `url`.

Within an *expression* the syntax `(type)` is a *cast operation*, an operation which changes the static type of its sub-expression. For example:

```
(double)3
```

takes the integer expression `3` and casts it to a `double` value.

In your method call:

```
[self addWebView:(NSURL *)];
```

you are calling `addWebView:` and passing it as argument the result of the expression:

```
(NSURL *)
```

which is half of a cast expression - you've provided no value to cast. Hence the error.

What you need is a *value* of type `NSURL *` to pass to `addWebView:`, from your code this value will be the URL of the page you wish to load. You have to decide where you obtain this from.

HTH

Comment: Sorry this question is canceled. I did everything wrong, already understand how to do this. Thank you for your help.